# Subquery SQL , get the count of ID's based on the subquery results

Tags: sql, subquery

I have written a sub query like this-

```
Select ID, count(*) as cn from xyz group by 1
```

Results in an output of-

| ID | cn |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 45 |

Now I am doing this query -

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN temp.cn > 10 THEN Count(DISTINCT id)
       END AS cn_10,
       CASE
         WHEN temp.cn <= 10 THEN Count(DISTINCT id)
       END AS cn_9
FROM   (SELECT id,
               Count(*) AS cn
        FROM   xyz
        GROUP  BY 1) AS temp;
```

hoping to get an output like

| cn_10 | cn_9 |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | 400 |

But I keep getting this error,

> SQL compilation error: [temp.cn] is not a valid group by expression

Comment: You can't refer to `cn` since you're not grouping by it, which is necessary due to aggregating with `count`. You need to implement the case expression within the aggregation - also note distinct is irrelevant since Id is already in distinct groups in the inner query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case expression within the aggregation like below, untested of course but does this work for you?

```
select
  Count(case when cn  > 10 then 1 end) cn_10,
  Count(case when cn <= 10 then 1 end) cn_9
from (
    select id, Count(*) cn
    from xyz
    group by Id
)t;
```

Comment: thanks Stu, the solution works, thanks for the explanation as well, appreciate it.